# Elasticsearch Is ML disabled for newer ES versions?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm using 7.8.1 version

I'm trying to upload csv data

I hit the link of `Upload data from log file Import a CSV, NDJSON, or log file`

And it takes me to `/app/ml#/filedatavisualizer`  and shows the following error

{"statusCode":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"Not Found"}

There's discussion, at https://github.com/elastic/kibana/pull/24260 , they say it's been resolved, but it's not..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer,

`you need to add the machine_learning_user or machine_learning_admin role to the user.`

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/filedatavisualizer-is-only-reachable-when-using-a-user-assigned-to-the-original-super-admin-role-like-elastic/221270/2